# Nagios SNMP Process check hangs on stale nfs mount

Tags: perl, snmp, nagios, nfs

I just got given this assignment at work and it is WAY over my head.  We have a nagios monitoring script that goes and and runs a process check.  We have had an NFS server that has been having issues lately and if it goes down, all of the machines that have it mounted start failing their process checks because the NFS mount is hung and has hung the SNMP check.

The check script is a perl nagios script that uses the NET::SNMP library.  I'm pretty sure that it is just the generic nagios script.  The script is found at http://nagios.manubulon.com/check_snmp_process.pl

Please help me understand what is going on.

EDIT: The nfs mount in question is for oracle RMAN backups that require the mount to be hard.

Comment: What exactly does the plugin return for the affected systems? Unknown? Critical? Is there an associated error message? Is SNMP timing out?

Comment: ERROR: Alarm signal (Nagios time-out)

It is hitting its timeout.  

If I shorten the script's timeout I get:
ERROR: Process name table : No response from remote host 'x.x.x.x'.

Comment: [Enable debugging](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP#debug---set-or-get-the-debug-mode-for-the-module) for `Net::SNMP` and run the plugin manually from the command line to see exactly where it's getting hung up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple - NFS is designed to tolerate server reboots. NFS calls to a mounted file system when it's mounted `hard` will therefore block and wait for the server to respond. This is to ensure that no data is lost or processes are suspended - they simply 'stall' - which'll be the problem you're having.

There's a mount option to nfs that avoids this problem - simply specify `soft` when mounting (either in fstab, or `-o soft` when doing it manually).

Be warned though - you'll get errors when accessing the NFS mount. Most things will tolerate this scenario, but it's always possible that badly written scripts or programs will fall over.

Comment: Thank you.
We're aware of the soft option. Unfortunately this NFS server is used for oracle RMAN backups that require a hard mount.

Comment: Then all your processes that are accessing the mount will stall whenever it becomes unavailable. That's by design. This will probably include your `snmpd` if it queries the mount table at any point.

Comment: That's the issue. This check is trying to access the mount table and I can't understand the code to see where it is doing it or how to stop it.

Comment: So turns out there was a separate check that monitored the disk usage.  it was blocking the snmpd process that in turn cause the process checks to fail.

Comment: @gfreestone You should make that a separate answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out there was a separate check that monitored the disk usage.  it was blocking the snmpd process that in turn cause the process checks to fail.